# I am getting a VB error '2467' with this routine ONLY. Other routines using SAME principle recipe are working well

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I am using MS Access 2016, and I have a form with a subForm. In other forms (8), I have created, with the same "recipe" - they work fine... subForm loads and receives data from the VBA query. In this case, I keep getting this - Microsoft Visual Basic Run-time error '2467': "The expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist." I am using the SAME process in other forms and it works well. HELP!?

The context of the code I am adding is hard to show because I use a routine for creating the recordset called GetSQLRst. My main form is called frmCustomerForm, and my subForm is called frmCustomerFormSub.

Here is my code block:

```
strSQL = "SELECT CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerCity, CustomerState, CustomerZIP " & vbCfLf & _ 
         "FROM Customers cust " & vbCfLf & _
         "LEFT JOIN REF_STATUS_TYPE st ON cust.STATUS = st.CODE " & vbCfLf & _  
         "WHERE cust.ID = '" Me!frmCustomerForm!UserID "' " & vbCfLf & _
         "ORDER by CustomerName DESC"

Set Forms!frmCustomerForm!frmCustomerFormSub.Form.Recordset = GetSQLRst(strSQL, True)
```

When I set a breakpoint at the top of this routine, The error occurs at the "Set Forms!" line.

Comment: Is cust.id numeric or text type?  You dont need the carriage returns either.  Is this code being run from the main form or a subform?

Comment: cust.id is numeric. Code is being run from the MAIN form. Main form calls the subForm

Comment: If `cust.id` really is numeric, you should omit the `'`s and for sure you forgot two `&`s: `"WHERE cust.ID = " & Me!frmCustomerForm!UserID & " " & vbCfLf`

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-write the who form with the query. Once I did the error went away.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.